# WSO2 configuration Passthrough Proxy

Tags: rest, wso2, mediator

Hi i want to build a proxy definition in a use case in which:

1)i have a client

2) WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

3) 2 REST services: R1 and R2

i want this to happen:

1) Client sends a request to an ESB proxy

2) proxy forwards the request to R1

3) if the R1's response rises no any error, the same response should be sent the client and to R2, otherwhise a fault message should be sent back to che client.

Could anyone help me to write this condifuration?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with service chaining. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/ and http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Service+Chaining+Example explains service chaining in soap, but it is similar to rest.

Comment: thanks for the help... in my use case, i cannot import the two REST services R1 and R2 inside the ESB. They have to be in separate Application container, like Tomcat. So, maybe could it be solved by using Mediator?

Comment: Of course. Where the services are deployed is irrelevant here. Configure the endpoint to call those services correctly.

Comment: i followed your suggestion. It seems to be the right way...but now im facing up to this:client sends a REST request to the R1service. R1 answers with a JSON/XML object from which i have to get a "Code" element and a "DocID".If Code == ok i have to send a REST request to the R2Service appending the DocID to it. (i.e. localhost:8080/service/MyR2service/DocID).I used the Switch mediator to get the Code(only xml, not json?) and DocID.How can i build a RESTRequest to R2Service appending this param to the query url?I thought about Callout mediator but i have no idea how to use it with rest Request